# Trouble Creating First Yii Application

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

Here is where I'm at. I am running MAMP on my Mac, and I have Yii in my htdocs folder. I don't understand the yiic.php part of it. I got it working once after numerous tries, but I the folder structure wasn't how I wanted it. So, with my folder structure being:

- yii

  - framework>
  - requirements>

Where exactly would I navigate to in the Terminal, and what would I type. I've been navigating into to Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Yii and then once in there running this command:

```
php framework/yiic.php webapp testdrive
```

After that I get the Yes/No question, run "Yes", it does its thing, and I get this folder structure:

- yii>

  - framework>
  - requirements>
  - testdrive>

    - assets>
    - css>
    - images>
    - index-test.php
    - index.php
    - protected>
    - themes>

Then I navigate in my browser to: http://localhost:8888/yii/testdrive/ and I get nothing...any idea what I am doing wrong?

Any help will be much appreciated! :) Thanks!

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had deleted the "testdrive" folder, but not the "framework" and "requirements" folders, and they had some settings changed in them that were preventing any new installs from working. So all I had to do was delete everything and completely start over :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but make the Y in yii a capital letter.  This is assuming that the directory Yii does indeed have a capital Y in it.  Unix/Linux machines have case sensitivity when it comes to these sorts of things.

As for your directory structure, you can have the Yii framework files live outside of your web folder if you want to.  The "testdrive" directory is all you need inside of the htdocs folder.  That said, the framework files can live in the folder as well, but it's generally considered insecure.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part, the "yii" in my folder structure isn't capatalized. My bad

Comment: All the yiic.php command does is act as a project generator to create the default testdrive directory.  Assuming you didn't move either folder after you created it, you should be good to go.  Out of curiosity, what kind of error do you get when trying to access the web app from the browser?  Is MAMP running (can you go to http://localhost:8888/ and see anything?)

Comment: I don't get an error, I just get a blank page...you are supposed to get a sample application like the one shown on this page: [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app ]

Comment: Do you know how to turn on php error reporting?  If not, google it and turn it on with MAMP (You'll edit your php.ini file and restart MAMP).  The errors that show up should tell you something.  I need to run, but goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but I am sure that I did not delete any file there. Fortunately, I try to restart apache server, and I revisite my test website, and it is working.

I use MAMP on Mac Lion. Hope this information would be helpful.